# Get string response from Observable

Tags: angular, subscribe

I´m retrieving a String from backend:

```
String value = "{I am here}";
```

On my service:

```
getValue(): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.get<String>(this.myURL);
  }
```

On my component I´m subscribing:

```
String myMessage;

  getValue(): void {
    this.myService.getValue()
    .subscribe(message=> {
        this.myMessage= myMessage;
        console.log("WHY NOT ENTER HERE?)

);
  });
```

What I´m doing wrong for not even getting the message from console.log?

Comment: Can be any error. Add `error` block to your subscription and console in there to see the error.

Comment: btw, a bit irrelevant here, but there's a difference in `string` and `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to be specific about the responseType if you want to use string.

Here is the doc https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

In your case, the `getValue`should do this:

```
return this.http.get(this.myURL, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Note that you don't need to use `<string>`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there is a mistake in your code, probably the reason you can't assign any value to `myMessage`:

Your code:

```
String myMessage;

  getValue(): void {
    this.myService.getValue()
    .subscribe(message=> {
        this.myMessage= myMessage;
        console.log("WHY NOT ENTER HERE?)

);
  });
```

It should be:

```
String myMessage;

  getValue(): void {
    this.myService.getValue()
    .subscribe(message=> {
        this.myMessage= message;
        console.log("WHY NOT ENTER HERE?)

);
  });
```

Notice the value assignment part in the callback function, you've used the wrong variable.

Hope it helps.